# Is there any method to find the corresponding word just by telling the coordinate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Like I am viewing a webpage which is full of words, can I get exactly which word I am reading by providing the coordinate of my gazing?

I know `document.elementFromPoint` can tell the tag, but I need more preciously till word level.

I just wanna run my code as a Chrome plugin. So the Chrome-only functions are also okay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of 'Get DOM text node from point?' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597157/get-dom-text-node-from-point

Comment: @Robin No, not duplicate. I want the exact word instead of the whole tag. that link returns tags.

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143534/get-the-position-of-text-within-an-element