# jQuery - Use Body Text As Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, typeerror

How we can use all `texts` inside `body`element as selector just like any other selectors (ie.: id, class, input, etc.)? I want to do something when any text in the body is hovered or clicked.

Example:

```
$("body > text").on('mouseover', function(){
 alert("Any text in the body is hovered!");
});
```

I tried this:

```
$("body").text().on('mouseover', function(){
 alert("Any text in the body is hovered!");
});
```

but it is returning this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).text(...).on is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first case didn't attach the event as there is no element with tagname text. and second one failed as jquery `.text()` return string and on method is used for jquery objects of dom elements which causes the error for you.

You need to simply attach the event to body element.:

```
$("body").on('mouseover', function(){
 alert("Any text in the body is hovered!");
});
```

you can also use all selector to attach event to all the inner elements:

```
$("body *").on('mouseover', function(){
 alert("Any text in the body is hovered!");
});
```

Comment: Isn't it will also select image and any other stuffs than text?

Comment: that is the reason i would suggest you to attch event to body and then use stopPropogation for elements on which you do not want event to occur. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389459/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-im-hovering-over-text

Answer (score 0):

you can put your body text in `<span> or <p>` tags and can easily attached mouseover event in jquery i.e:

HTML:

```
<body>
<p>this is text</p>
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
$("body p").on('mouseover', function(){
 alert("Any text in the body is hovered!");
});
```

Comment: What if the only wrapper for the text is `body` tag and there other stuffs like image, while I only want to select text?