# different function to execute depending on cursor location (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a button in a html form which executes a function when it is clicked:

```
<input type="button" onclick="do_action_1();">
```

But I have two functions:

```
do_action_1()
do_action_2()
```

I also have two text boxes:

```
<input id="tb1" type="text" name="textbox1">
<input id="tb2" type="text" name="textbox2">
```

If the user's cursor is in textbox1, I want the button to carry out

```
do_action_1
```

but if the user's cursor is in textbox2, I want the button to carry out

```
do_action_2.
```

I'm not sure where to begin when doing this so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3395856/8811872) seems somewhat helpful: "Basically the idea is that you use hover to set a flag on the element that the mouse is over it/no longer over it. And then you write a function that checks for that flag."

Comment: Thanks Kevin. But I'm talking about when the cursor is actually active inside a text box rather than where the mouse is hovering. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `onclick` event for each input and inside it change the target element attribute `attr` value

```js
$('#tb1').click(function(){
  $('.change_function').attr("onclick","do_action_1();");
});
$('#tb2').click(function(){
  $('.change_function').attr("onclick","do_action_2();");
});

function do_action_1(){
  alert("function 1 is selected !");
}
function do_action_2(){
  alert("function 2 is selected !");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="do_action_1();" class="change_function" value="Change Function">
Function 1<input id="tb1" type="text" name="textbox1">
Function 2<input id="tb2" type="text" name="textbox2">
```

### Edit

You can also use `focus` event as **katz** and **Eddie** suggested in comments below, bacause the input field could be active without clicking on it like by hitting the tab key.

```
$('#tb1').focus(function(){
  $('.change_function').attr("onclick","do_action_1();");
});
$('#tb2').focus(function(){
  $('.change_function').attr("onclick","do_action_2();");
});
```

Comment: What if i click on `#tb1` and press tab. Now the cursor is on `#tb2` but When click on btn. Still saying **function 1 is selected !**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand your question
but maybe `onfocus` handle is helpful

```
var tb1 = document.getElementById('tb1');
var tb2 = document.getElementById('tb2');

tb1.onfocus = function(){
  console.log('1')
  do_action_1
}

tb2.onfocus = function(){
  console.log('2')
  do_action_2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually use `onfocus` to set a class on the textbox, then use that class to see what action to perform :

```
$('input[name^="textbox"]').on('focus',function () {
  $('input[name^="textbox"]').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

function do_action () {
  if ($('input[name="textbox1"]').is('.active')) do_action_1();
  else do_action_2();
}
```